# FOTORAMA не отображает ALT

Tags: изображения, slider, img, слайдер

Имею данный код:

```html
<div class="fotorama">
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang.jpg" alt="photo1" title="title1" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang2.jpg" alt="photo2" title="title2" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang3.jpg" alt="photo3" title="title3" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang4.jpg" alt="photo4" title="title4" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang5.jpg" alt="photo5" title="title5" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang6.jpg" alt="photo6" title="title6" />
     <img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang7.jpg" alt="photo7" title="title7" />
</div>
```

После запуска которого на сайте появляеться удобный слайдер прокрутки изображений.

[image: как выглядит слайдер фоторама fotorama]

Однако в консоли браузера все alt & title атрибуты пропадают..

```html
<img src="images/photos/fari-ford-mustang.jpg" class="fotorama__img" style="width: 666.429px; height: 500px; left: 47.1137px; top: 0px;">
```

Пример на сайте: [пример fotorama](https://ebolt.net/uk/catalog/spares/audi-80-b2/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаг первый:
Открыть файл fotorama.dev.js и найти следущую строку:

```
frameData.state = '';
```

После нее добавить это:

```js
if ( frameData.data.hasOwnProperty('alt') ) {
   img.alt= frameData.data.alt;
}
if ( frameData.data.hasOwnProperty('title') ) {
   img.title= frameData.data.title;
}
```

Шаг второй:
Найти строчку:

```
height = numberFromMeasure(imgData.height || $img.attr('height'));
```

И заменить на это:

```js
height = numberFromMeasure(imgData.height || $img.attr('height')),
alt = $img.attr('alt'),
title = $img.attr('title');
if (alt){
   $.extend(imgData, {
   alt: alt
   });
}
if (title){
   $.extend(imgData, {
   title: title
   });
}
```

Шаг третий:
Минифицировать и переназвать в fotorama.js
проверено в 4.6.4 версии.

Решение взято с github:
[fotorama.js](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/439#issuecomment-185284860)